# mobile browsers and compatibility with Grails

Tags: grails

Are there any settings or configurations need to be done in the Grails application to support the viewing the application from mobile's browser (mobiles or Tablets ) . 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, Grails doesn't require any specific configuration to serve HTML/CSS/etc. to a mobile device.

Comment: so my application will be optimized automatically , when it has been viewed  from mobile devices ?

Comment: No, Grails doesn't do anything special at all for mobile browsers. Your question wasn't about "optimizing" the output for mobile devices. Your question was "would it serve content to mobile browsers without any additional configuration". Optimization for mobile vs not mobile is a concern that falls outside of the scope of Grails. Grails doesn't care what device it sends the HTML/CSS/etc. to. A browser is a browser to Grails.

Comment: thanks for clarification, so regarding the optimization for mobile devices is there any settings or configurations ?

Comment: Nope, there are no settings in Grails regarding mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Think of Grails application like regular Server Side code. The HTML generated is the same for mobile devices and browsers.

You *can* and *should* optimize your site for mobile display - but that's the same for every website, and is not unique to Grails.

All client-server communication is identical, no matter the client.